# How to set up VPS with domain name and certificate

Tags: dns, ssl, certificate, domain

I would like to set up a webserver on my own domain, accessible anywhere via https.

I already have a VPS from Linode. I've read about getting a free SSL certificate using [this script](https://github.com/Neilpang/acme.sh)...which requires a domain name to work. However, I'm not quite sure how to get a domain name.

- Can I get a free domain name? I've tried Freenom but I get the impression that it will only work if you explicitly use their DNS servers, which aren't part of the full public chain.
- Otherwise, how cheaply can I get a domain? I don't really care what it looks like (don't even care if it's a subdomain), just as long as anybody can type `https://what.ev.er` and get to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar).  Depending on where you live, there should be a local provider, or you can select a large global provider such as [godaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/).

You should be able to get fairly cheap domains (the godaddy site indicates an $11.99 price) for a .com domain.

Comment: Note that that is $11.99 ***for the first year*** with (apparently) an even higher annual charge thereafter.